# VirtualAlloc()failed:[0x00000008]Not enough memory resources available to process this command

Tags: magento2

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1218445312) (tried to allocate 134217728 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90

While installing data migration tool using composer.

I have set the memory_limit=-1 in php.ini file.

Comment: If you're using command line try to put before the command memory_limit=-1 or COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 ex: COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=1 composer update

Comment: @RuiSilva I did it but the same issue is arising.

Comment: Then, do your machine have enough resources by itself?

Comment: @RuiSilva How to check resources?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in command line tbh, I usually use massiveGRID e can easily check, but if you have a provider you should have the specs somewhere or can ask him, you can even expose this situation to him and maybe try to increase the limits on the provider side even if just for testing

Comment: @RuiSilva I am testing this on local server xampp only

Comment: If you run 'php -i | grep memory_limit' what's the value? it might need a lot, anyway memory_limit=-1 should fix that

Comment: @RuiSilva I already mentioned about it as I set memory_limit=-1 beforehand.

Comment: I asked because I had a magento and had to change in php.ini, user.ini and in .htaccess and if you got a php-fpm.conf that overrides so it was to make sure it was really set

Answer (score 0):

faced same problem the solution is:
1)download the VC15 x64 Thread Safe (2020-Oct-01 13:06:05) zip file for php 7.2.
2)make a folder called php72 on dekstop.
3)copy all files from php zip folder and paste into php72 folder.
4)rename php.ini-development to php.ini.
5)enable all extensions in php.ini file.
6) save php.ini and run this command from cli.

```
"C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\php72\php.exe" -d memory_limit=-1 "C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar" update
```

Thanks.